# Storing an array in a database

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have a list of 2048 doubles that represent the amplitude of different samples in a signal. I'm constantly re-sampling the signal (say 20 times every second) and would like to store the data in an SQL database.

One complete measurement of the signal looks something like this:

```
List<double> sineCurve = new List<double>();

for (int i = 0; i < 2048; ++i)
{
   sineCurve.Add(50 + 50 * Math.Sin(i / Math.PI));
}
```

What's the best way to store this data? The simplest way seems to be to create a table with 2049 columns and store each measurement as a new row:

```
string sql = "create table sample( measurement_id int not null, sample_value1 double, sample_value2 double, ... sample_value1 double2048 )";
```

Is this the preferred way of storing this type of data?

Edit: I would like to run a test where data is collected and saved to the database continuously over a few days. Then I would like to process the data by looking for certain patterns in each list of samples, min/max values and so forth.

Comment: That doesn't seem the simplest way at all. what about a table with varbinary(maxlength) field

Comment: You could also create a table with measurement_id, index and value. Where index is from 0 to 2048. Save your values with increasing index.

Comment: It is impossible to create a table that has so many columns unless you compile sqlite [https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html] Other than that, agree with @feal

Comment: oh this is sqlite, eek im not sure they even have a binary field

Comment: How do you want to query this data?

Comment: @TheGeneral I want to process each list of 2048 floats separately and look for certain patterns, min max values etc.

Comment: If you are not going to query over this data - you can save that as binary blob (it's of fixed size - 2048 * 8 bytes). If you are going to query - then follow feal suggestion.

Comment: @Evk I will be collecting some other data at different intervals (temeprature etc) that I would like to store in a related table. I might need to perform some queries.

Comment: @Q-bertsuit performing queries is fine, but not over these floats. I mean if you will need something like "give me all samples which include amplitudes over X" - storing in blob won't work.

Comment: @feal I'll try this suggestion, thanks!

Comment: @Evk Ok I think I understand. I would be working on the samples directly. At most I would query for something like "Give me all the samples in all measurements between 5 and 6 o'clock"

Comment: How are you analysing this data? Apparently R is a good tool for this although I haven't had the opportunity to use it. Are you saying you willhave 3.5 million samples in total? (20 X 60 X 60 X 24 X 2). Can SQLLite even handle 20 inserts per second or 3 million rows?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, insert should not be a problem, especially if he submit all value to a stored procedure at once.

Comment: For the  "Give me all the samples in all measurements between 5 and 6 o'clock" querry you cn have an other table storing mesurment_Id and detail like time stamp so you can querry exactly what critera you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a table like this, where you store all your samples in a measurement in one BLOB-entry:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (id (primary key) ,  generated_at (timestamp), sample (blob), SequenceNr (integer));
```

Then if you want to look for measurements in a given time range it would look kind of like this:

```
SELECT m.sample FROM measurement m
WHERE m.generated_at BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
ORDER BY m.SequenceNr;
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! I have a couple of questions: 1. Why do I need an id AND a SequenceNr? Would it not be the same number? 2. The BLOB data will look like gibberish right? I will have to use some program to convert it back to an array before it will make sense?

Comment: 1. The sequenceNr is used to make sure in which order the sample came in.  I would not use the ID for that. 2. Yes, you probably have to write a method which converts it back to an array of floats.

Comment: Although it would be nice to just hand over the database file to someone and then they could use a DB-browser to look at the data directly, I definitely see the advantage of using a blob. Thanks again!

Comment: I wonder how this solution would support processing "the data by looking for certain patterns in each list of samples, min/max values and so forth." You cannot run queries against blob fields, this is why I suggested to pre-process each record before saving.

Comment: @PepitoSh Thats a good point. In that case I would write each sample in a separate entry where we can identify by SequenceNr and timestamp to which measure it belongs to or one can add a Mapping Table between Measurement and Sample and store them in separate Tables to identify to which measure the sample belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

You should know in advance what kind of queries you wish to run against your data. Find those relevant values before saving a record and put in separate fields. Otherwise save the array in a blob field as binary.

If you find out other queries you have to reprocess the blob values by picking the values you need.